# Create folder after every execution with different names

Tags: python, file-io, directory

I'm trying to make a program which creates a new folder with different names inside a folder for every execution being made. I've pasted the code below I'm using:

```
import os


current_directory = os.getcwd()
name = "Day 1"


def folder_create(path, folder_name):
    folder_names = [folder for folder in os.listdir(
        path) if os.path.isdir(folder)]
    if folder_name not in folder_names:
        os.makedirs(folder_name)
    else:
        folder_num = folder_name.split(' ')[1]
        new_folder_name = f'Day {int(folder_num) + 1}'
        os.makedirs(new_folder_name, exist_ok=False)
        folder_name = new_folder_name
    return folder_name


if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = folder_create(current_directory, name)
    print(name)
```

This code only works twice meaning that it's only able to create two folders i.e, (Day 1 and Day 2) after executed two times but after then it gives FileExistError. Please help me find a way around as I just want it to create a new folder with every next day name i,e(Day 1, Day 2, Day 3) for each time executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work nicely. The real issue with your code was you kept supplying the same "name" argument to the `folder_create()` function.

All i've done is remove the need for supplying the name argument.

What it now does instead is to get the list of directories, sort the list, then get the last one using negative indexing. It then uses the last one create the new folder name. have fun

```
import os


current_directory = os.getcwd()
name = "Day 1"


def folder_create(path):
    folder_names = [folder for folder in os.listdir(
        path) if os.path.isdir(folder)]
    folder_names.sort()
    if "Day 1" not in folder_names:
        os.makedirs('Day 1')
    else:
        folder_num = folder_names[-1].split(' ')[1]
        new_folder_name = f'Day {int(folder_num) + 1}'
        os.makedirs(new_folder_name, exist_ok=False)
        folder_name = new_folder_name
    return folder_name


if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = folder_create(current_directory)
    print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

This Solution Might Work For You-

```py
import os
import random


current_directory = os.getcwd()
day_names = []

for i in range(0, 10+1):  # 10 or Or Other Number+1 To Get Day Names That Number Of Times
    day_names.append('Day '+str(i))


def folder_create(path, folder_name):
    folder_names = [folder for folder in os.listdir(
        path) if os.path.isdir(folder)]
    if folder_name not in folder_names:
        os.makedirs(folder_name)
    else:
        folder_num = folder_name.split(' ')[1]
        new_folder_name = f'Day {int(folder_num) + random.randint(0, 10000)}'  # To Get A Random Day Name If It Already Exixts
        os.makedirs(new_folder_name, exist_ok=False)
        folder_name = new_folder_name
    return folder_name


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for name in day_names:  # Looping To Get Each Day Name
        name = folder_create(current_directory, name)
        print(name)
```

Comment: Thanks @Aryan for the reply, but using your solution I get to generate 10 folders e.,g(..Day 10), all at once, I was thinking if It's possible to generate each folder for each execution. Please do let me know how do I go about doing that.

Comment: Ok, Let Me Try.

Comment: this solution generates random folder names, op didn't specify randomness though. try removing that maybe

Comment: Yes Will Work On That @TochiBedford. Thanks For Reporting The Bug :-)